# Java - Trigger graceful shutdown using process id on Windows

Tags: java, windows, shutdown

I have a program that will be running on a Windows machine that I want to use `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()` to gracefully shut down my program and wait for all threads to finish before exiting.

I can trigger this shutdown from a Powershell or batch script using the pid. The java program runs as a background process so as far as I know there's no way to feed the equivalent of a Ctrl-C command to the process.

Things I have tried:

`Stop-Process` killed the process without triggering the shutdown hook

`taskkill` returned an error saying the process could not be terminated, and that it must be terminated forcefully

`taskkill /f` killed the process without triggering the shutdown hook

How can I trigger Java's graceful shutdown on Windows? I've read there's a way to send the signal through the JVM but I haven't been able to find a way to do that on Windows.

Comment: Sadly java does not guarantee a clean shutdown even with a shutdown hook.
Have you tried using `ProcessHandle` from jdk9 instead? You can call a `ProcessHandle.onExit()` function to execute actions upon process termination. That might get called when doing `taskkill` but I haven't tried it myself

Comment: Task Manager and taskkill gracefully terminate a process by sending `WM_CLOSE` to its top-level windows. taskkill also sends `WM_CLOSE` to the message-only windows of a process, at least in Windows 10.

Comment: Unfortunately we're using jdk8 currently so ProcessHandle isn't available and upgrading our java version may not be possible, but thanks for the suggestion.